# Definite integral $\int_{0}^{+ \infty}e^{itx}e^{-x} \frac{x^n}{n!}dx$

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

Definite integral $$\int_{0}^{+ \infty}e^{itx}e^{-x} \frac{x^n}{n!}dx$$

I very much need this for probability, the answer is $$\frac{1}{(1-it)^{n+1}}.$$
I just don't know how to come to this myself. Can someone help out that has experience in integrating? I think the gamma function must be used.

Comment: I tried using the gamma function, because i am convinced that it must be done using it, but to no avail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One may observe that
$$
\frac1{\lambda}=\int_0^{+\infty} e^{-\lambda x}dx, \quad \Re \lambda>0.\tag1
$$
Then differentiating $n$ times with respect to $\lambda$ gives
$$
\frac{(-1)^n\:n!}{\lambda^{n+1}}=(-1)^n\int_0^{+\infty} x^n e^{-\lambda x}dx, \quad \Re \lambda>0.\tag2
$$
Apply $(2)$ with $\lambda=1-it$.

Answer (score 1):

The following might help
$$
\int_0^\infty dx e^{x (\mathrm{i}t-1)}=\frac{\mathrm{i}}{\mathrm{i}+t},\qquad \mathrm{Im}(t)>-1
$$
and 
$$
\partial_t^{(n)} e^{\mathrm{i}tx} =(\mathrm{i}x)^n e^{\mathrm{i}tx}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Use integration by parts n+1 times

Comment: This answer is not helpful, since the integral has *three* factors as written. Just what do you mean for $u$ and $v$? Have you actually done the problem to completion so you are sure this hint works?

Comment: @Rory Daulton let $u=\frac{x^n}{n!}$ and $dv=e^{-x(1-it)}$, is there something wrong with this method?

Comment: @RoryDaulton: It's a perfectly fine integration by parts if you fuse the two exponentials into a single one. What a cruel destiny for the answerer, to see his first post ever on MSE downvoted yet correct!

Comment: @AlexM.: I am not the downvoter, but I did see that given hint was not clear.  Someone has also voted to delete this answer, so I am glad that bob kelso explained better. And Bob, I do not see anything wrong with that method--it just was not clear without further explanation.